# Upload multiple files in Laravel 4

Tags: php, file, upload, laravel

Here is my controller code for uploading multiple files and I am passing key and value from 'postman' rest API client on Google Chrome. I am adding multiple files from postman but only 1 file is getting upload.

```
public function post_files() {
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","txt","pdf","doc","rtf","docx","xls","xlsx");
    foreach($_FILES['file'] as $key => $abc) {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $filename= $temp[0];
        $destinationPath = 'upload/'.$filename.'.'.$extension;

        if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)&&($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)) {
            if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            if (file_exists($destinationPath)) {
                echo $filename." already exists. ";
            } else {
                $uploadSuccess=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$destinationPath);
                if( $uploadSuccess ) {
                    $document_details=Response::json(Author::insert_document_details_Call($filename,$destinationPath));
                    return $document_details; // or do a redirect with some message that file was uploaded
                // return Redirect::to('authors')
                } else {
                    return Response::json('error', 400);
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

I have tried this code also but it returns me location of a file in temporary folder

```
$file = Input::file('file');
            echo count($file);
```

and
 `echo count($_FILES['file']);`
returns me always 5.Can anyone tell me why?

and why `foreach(Input::file('file') as $key => $abc)`  gives the error invalid arguments

Answer (score 22):

### Solution:

You can get all files by simply doing:

```
$allFiles = Input::file();
```

### Explanation:

The class `Input` is actually a Facade for the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class (Yes, just like the `Request` facade - they both serve as the "Face" for the same class!**).

That means you can use any methods available in Request .

If we search for the function [`file()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L254), we see it works like this:

```
public function file($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return $this->retrieveItem('files', $key, $default);
}
```

Now, `retrieveItem()` is a protected method, so we can't just call it from our Controller directly. Looking deeper, however, we see that [we can pass the `file()` method "null"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L254) for the key. If we do so, then we'll get all the items!

```
protected function retrieveItem($source, $key, $default)
{
    if (is_null($key))
    {
        return $this->$source->all();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->$source->get($key, $default, true);
    }
}
```

So, if we call `Input::file()`, the Request class will internally run `$this->retrieveItem('files', null, null)` which will in turn run `return $this->files->all();` and we will get all the files uploaded.

** Note that `Input` Facade has the extra method [get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php#L14) available in it.

Answer (score 21):

Not using any API, but this might outline the principle.

I set up this routes.php file, whick will help you with upload test.

**routes.php**

```
// save files
Route::post('upload', function(){
    $files = Input::file('files');

    foreach($files as $file) {
                // public/uploads
        $file->move('uploads/');
    }
});

// Show form
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo Form::open(array('url' => 'upload', 'files'=>true));
    echo Form::file('files[]', array('multiple'=>true));
    echo Form::submit();
    echo Form::close();
});
```

**Notice the input name, files[]:** If uploading multiple files under the same name, include brackets as well.

Answer (score 3):

the above solutions wont work with multiple files as the return will fire as soon the first item gets validated ,so here is a solution after several hours of head-wall banging. inspired by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtuds0l8bA

```
// route
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('main');
});
Route::post('up', 'FUplaodController@store');

// controller
class FUplaodController extends \BaseController {
    public function store()
    {
        if (Input::hasFile('images'))
        {
            $files = Input::file('images');
            $rules = [
                'file' => 'required|image'
            ];
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads';

            foreach ($files as $one)
            {
                $v = Validator::make(['file' => $one], $rules);
                if ($v->passes())
                {
                    $filename       = $one->getClientOriginalName();
                    $upload_success = $one->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                    if ($upload_success)
                    {
                        $done[] = $filename;
                        Session::flash('done', $done);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $filename = $one->getClientOriginalName();
                    $not[] = $filename;
                    Session::flash('not', $not);
                }
            }
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
        }
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors('choose a file');
    }
}

// view
<!-- uploaded -->
@if (Session::has('done'))
    @foreach (Session::get('done') as $yes)
        <li>{{ $yes }}</li>
    @endforeach
    <p style="color: #2ecc71">Uploaded</p>
    <br>
@endif

<!-- not uploaded -->
@if (Session::has('not'))
    @foreach (Session::get('not') as $no)
        <li>{{ $no }}</li>
    @endforeach
    <p style="color: #c0392b">wasnt uploaded</p>
    <br>
@endif

<!-- errors -->
<p style="color: #c0392b">{{ $errors->first() }}</p>
<hr>

<!-- form -->
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'up', 'files'=>true]) }}
    {{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple'=>true]) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Upload') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

u basicly save the filenames in an array and pass those arrays to a session then only add `return` when the loop has finished.

Comment: Amazing, very well described. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Form :-**
Form opening tag must have ‘files’=>true and file field must have name [](with array) and ‘multiple’=>true

```
<?php 
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'apply/multiple_upload','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}
{{ Form::file('images[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }}
?>
```

**2. Add below code to your controller function :-**

```
<?php
// getting all of the post data
$files = Input::file('images');
foreach($files as $file) {
  // validating each file.
  $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
  $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
  if($validator->passes()){
    // path is root/uploads
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    // flash message to show success.
    Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
    return Redirect::to('upload');
  } 
  else {
    // redirect back with errors.
    return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
  }
}
?>
```

SOURCE : http://tutsnare.com/upload-multiple-files-in-laravel/

**EDIT: Reference source link is not working**.

Comment: Note: The php code just validate the first file and redirects immediatly. If there is no file, it returns void and no effect is shown. The link seems to be a good one though.

Comment: The source URL now redirects to some parked domain, FYI.

Comment: @damd  Sorry, Reference URL is not working. You can ask if you are having any trouble with the code.