# Iterate through multiple request files with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to iterate through the Request File objects in Laravel 4?
I'd like to do something like this:

```
foreach (Input::files() as $file) {
  $filename = str_random(8) . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  // ...
}
```

I'd like to use the Input:: approach instead of iterating the `$_FILES` array..
Thanks

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204781/upload-multiple-files-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0):

Going into Symfony code, you probably will be able to:

```
foreach (Request::instance()->files->all() as $file) {
  $filename = str_random(8) . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  // ...
}
```

Take a look at

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag
```

and

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag
```

For a better understanding of what you can do with them.

Comment: Strangle `$file` is an array of files for me