# Upload Multiple Images Via Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

How to upload multiple images through laravel 4? With the codes below I get only the last image. If I select imgA, imgB, imgC, and imgD, I saved only imgD. I need imgA, imgB, imgC, and imgD.

```
public function store()
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp = $date->format('U');
    $pid = Input::get('pid');

    $file = Input::file('image');

    if ($file->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
        $oriname = Str::lower(pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));

        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $fileName = $timestamp.'_'.$oriname.'.'.$extension; 
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); 
        $url = asset('images/'.$fileName);
    }

    $newImage = New Image;
    $newImage->property_id = $pid;
    $newImage->path = $url;
    if ($newImage->save()){
        return array('status'=>'Image saved.'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload multiple files in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204781/upload-multiple-files-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ..

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
$pid = Input::get('pid');
$files = Input::file('image');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
        $oriname = Str::lower(pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $fileName = $timestamp.'_'.$oriname.'.'.$extension; 
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName); 
        $url = asset('images/'.$fileName);
    }

    $newImage = New Image();
    $newImage->property_id = $pid;
    $newImage->path = $url;
    if (! $newImage->save()) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.